# Ajustar contenedor DIV de una tarjeta a la pantalla con HTML y CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo una Card View creada con HTML y CSS y también un problema que no logro solucionar.

Dentro de la tarjeta "Card View" tengo la imagen de portada, el título, una descripción y un enlace correspondiente. El inconveniente es que la tarjeta se muestra perfectamente bien en dispositivos de gran pantalla como una computadora, pero en dispositivos móviles con una pantalla reducida se ve sobresalido del margen DIV, lo que visualmente queda espantoso.

> Les dejo los códigos HTML y CSS completos:

```css
.cards-div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 0!important;
    padding-bottom: 0!important;
    padding: 6rem
}

@media (max-width: 60em) {
    .cards-div {
        padding: 3rem
    }
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 6rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr))!important;
    align-items: start
}

@media (max-width: 60em) {
    .grid {
        grid-gap: 3rem
    }
}

.grid__item {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: .4rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 3rem 6rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .2s
}

.grid__item:hover {
    transform: translateY(-0.5%);
    box-shadow: 0 4rem 8rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}

.card__img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 18rem;
    object-fit: cover
}

.card__content {
    padding: 3rem
}

.card__content a {
    color: #181818!important
}

.card__header {
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #0d0d0d;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem
}

.card__text {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    line-height: 1.7;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    margin-bottom: 2.5rem
}

.card__btn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #3363ff;
    background-color: #e6ecff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: .4rem;
    transition: .2s;
    cursor: pointer
}

.card__btn span {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    transition: .2s
}

.card__btn:hover,
.card__btn:active {
    background-color: #dce4ff
}

.card__btn:hover span,
.card__btn:active span {
    margin-left: 1.5rem!important
}

.snippet-fade {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(63, 169, 244, 0.9) 0, rgba(63, 169, 244, 0.9) 20%, rgba(63, 133, 244, 0) 100%);
    border-radius: 100px;
    font-weight: 700
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item">
    <div class="card"><a href="https://www.example.com/url"><img
      alt="Snowy Mountains" class="card__img"
      src="https://mcusercontent.com/ec104f3d77537e1962ab6441c/images/f9167dfd-9e60-4edd-b1ec.jpg"
    /></a>
    <div class="card__content">
    <h1 class="card__header"><a href="https://www.example.com/url"
      style="text-decoration:none">Title Example</a></h1>
    
    <p class="card__text"><em class="fa-calendar-alt far"
      style="padding-right:5px"></em>09/07/2020</p>
    
    <p class="card__text"><a href="https://www.example.com/url"
      style="text-decoration:none">Example Description</a></p>
    <a href="https://www.example.com/url"
      style="text-decoration:none"><strong class="card__btn"
    >Ampliar</strong></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **Así se ve en móviles:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver a la derecha del dispositivo (ver la portada como referencia), el contenedor entero sobresale causando que el usuario tenga que desplazarse hacia la derecha para ver todo el contenido.

Si tienes una solución, se agradece.

Comment: Mmm lo que puedes intentar es simplemente cambiar `@media (max-width: 60em)` por `@media screen and (max-width: 675px)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es porque en `.card__btn` tienes un ancho del 100% que no es necesario:

1. Los elementos de bloque toman automáticamente el ancho disponible
2. Cuando especificas ancho al 100%, se aplica lo anterior, con un pequeño detalle: los márgenes internos (padding) y externos (margin) se agregan a ese 100%, desbordando los límites del contenedor
3. Puedes omitir la asignación de ancho o aplicar [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) para evitar ese desbordamiento.

```css
.cards-div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 0!important;
    padding-bottom: 0!important;
    padding: 6rem
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 6rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr))!important;
    align-items: start
}

@media (max-width: 60em) {
    .grid {
        grid-gap: 3rem
    }
}

.grid__item {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: .4rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 3rem 6rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .2s
}

.grid__item:hover {
    transform: translateY(-0.5%);
    box-shadow: 0 4rem 8rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}

.card__img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 18rem;
    object-fit: cover
}

.card__content {
    padding: 3rem
}

.card__content a {
    color: #181818!important
}

.card__header {
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #0d0d0d;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem
}

.card__text {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    line-height: 1.7;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    margin-bottom: 2.5rem
}

.card__btn {
    display: block;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #3363ff;
    background-color: #e6ecff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: .4rem;
    transition: .2s;
    cursor: pointer
}

.card__btn span {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    transition: .2s
}

.card__btn:hover,
.card__btn:active {
    background-color: #dce4ff
}

.card__btn:hover span,
.card__btn:active span {
    margin-left: 1.5rem!important
}

.snippet-fade {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(63, 169, 244, 0.9) 0, rgba(63, 169, 244, 0.9) 20%, rgba(63, 133, 244, 0) 100%);
    border-radius: 100px;
    font-weight: 700
}

@media (max-width: 60em) {
    .cards-div {
        padding: 3rem
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item">
    <div class="card"><a href="https://www.example.com/url"><img
      alt="Snowy Mountains" class="card__img"
      src="https://mcusercontent.com/ec104f3d77537e1962ab6441c/images/f9167dfd-9e60-4edd-b1ec.jpg"
    /></a>
    <div class="card__content">
    <h1 class="card__header"><a href="https://www.example.com/url"
      style="text-decoration:none">Title Example</a></h1>
    
    <p class="card__text"><em class="fa-calendar-alt far"
      style="padding-right:5px"></em>09/07/2020</p>
    
    <p class="card__text"><a href="https://www.example.com/url"
      style="text-decoration:none">Example Description</a></p>
    <a href="https://www.example.com/url"
      style="text-decoration:none"><strong class="card__btn"
    >Ampliar</strong></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

De preferencia, coloca las *media queries* al final de tu CSS, así garantizas que todos los elementos estén definidos previamente.